# Check ESLint warnings with Firebase CLI without deploying functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint, firebase-cli

I have a bunch of ESLint warnings that I want to resolve, but don't want to go through troubleshooting them by continuously deploying a function. Is there a Firebase CLI command that I can use to *just* check for errors/warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use the Firebase CLI for this.  Use npm instead.  Notice in your package.json there a number of scripts that perform various tasks.  You want to run the "lint" script.

In your shell, change to the "functions" folder and run `npm run lint`. This will execute the named "lint" script defined in package.json.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Figured it was a straight forward answer haha.